# Pass names to a list and use 'contains' for each

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement

I have a dataframe that one of its columns called `proj` has a sentence in every row and in that sentence a name of a city is mentioned. I want to do an `if` condition that when a password is being passed a different city's data will be available.

```
proj
sd_32 New York
eo_31 Lisbon
..
```

Ex.

```
x = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\Dataset.csv', sep = ',')
while True:
    passw = input('Password').upper()
    if not passw in ('A','B'):
        print('Try again')
        continue
    else:
        break
if passw == 'A':
    df = x[x['proj'].str.contains('New York')]
    print(df) 
elif passw == 'B':
    df = x[x['proj'].str.contains('Lisbon')]
    print(df)
```

How to do this in a more Pythonic way?

I thought about making a list :

```
city = ['New York','Lisbon','Berlin',..] #unique names of cities
```

and then pass this in a code that for every individual city, depending the password does an `if` process like I did but with this idea. How can I proceed with this?

Comment: Also `if not passw in cities` will work to detect valid entries instead of having to repeat the valid keys for passw

Comment: @gsa Perhaps you can add another column with the mentioned city name and directly pick the row number based on that, instead of doing string compare in everystep later?   

Also can you give more concrete example with piece of dataframe?

Comment: The column needed is the one called proj, as shown in the question. What do you mean exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps use a dict with passwords as key, and city names as values: `cities = {'A': 'New York', 'B': 'Lisbon', ...}`. Admittedly, you still have to check for valid keys, but that happens in the loop above, when asking for the input password (using the dict keys):

```
cities = {'A': 'New York', 'B': 'Lisbon'}
x = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\Dataset.csv', sep = ',')
while True:
    passw = input('Password').upper()
    if passw not in cities:   # `in cities` same as `in cities.keys()`
        print('Try again')
        continue
    else:
        break
df = x[x['proj'].str.contains(cities[passw])]
print(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `dict` in your case

**Ex:**

```
d = {"A": 'New York', "B": 'Lisbon'}
if passw in d:
    df = x[x['proj'].str.contains(d[passw])]
```